# Unable to start the timer in a service in android

Tags: java, android, service, timer

I dont know whats wrong going on... I am not able to start a timer in my service. Following the code

```
public class BkgService extends Service{

private Timer ServUpdTimer = new Timer();
private static  long TMR_INTERVAL = 10*60*1000;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    StartServUpdateTask();
    }

private void StartServUpdateTask() {

        if(ServUpdTimer != null)
            ServUpdTimer.cancel();


        ServUpdTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        }, 0, TMR_INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

But when I reach to the line `ServUpdTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` I am getting the following exception

> 03-03 23:32:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
>   mt.android.app.BkgService@40544838 with Intent {
>   cmp=mt.android.app/.BkgService }: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Timer was canceled

I would be very grateful if someone can throw some light on this...

Comment: If you #cancel a Timer you have to create a new instance if you want to use it again. The first thing you do in your `StartServUpdateTask` is to kill the Timer & render it useless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the Javadoc for `Timer.cancel()`:

> Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

From the Javadoc for `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()`:

> Throws: IllegalStateException - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.

The `Timer` is cancelled immediately: you need to create a new instance:

```
private void StartServUpdateTask() {

    if(ServUpdTimer != null)
    {
        ServUpdTimer.cancel();
    }
    ServUpdTimer = new Timer();

    ...
}
```