# Restart a timer once it is cancelled

Tags: java, swing, timertask

I have invoked `cancel()` method of Timer class outside the `run()` method of `TimerTask` class.

I want to know is it possible to restart this timer?

On stop button I have invoked cancel()  method :-

```
private void stopBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
t.cancel();}
```

Here t is instance of Timer class.

Comment: ..how is this connected with Swing?  For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547267/unable-to-start-the-timer-in-a-service-in-android

Comment: u can possibly use same TimerTask with a new instance of Timer

Comment: you probably want to use javax.swing.Timer (vs. java.util.Timer)

Comment: Why did you post an uncompilable code snippet?  Again.. *For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).*

Answer (score 1):

You can't restart a Timer once cancelled - My advice would be to create a new one.  Obviously you could wrap this in your own restartable Timer implementation that merely creates a new Timer under the covers each time.